# log4net - Saving logs to a remote network location - Is it possible?

Tags: networking, location, log4net, logging

I'm wondering if it's possible to have log4net write logs to a remote network location?

e.g.

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="\\somesharedspace.network\logs\log"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
</appender>
```

Not sure if it makes a difference, but it's a Windows network.

Cheers,
Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this works. Question is of course if you really want to do this: It is usually slower then logging in a local file and the network share might not be available.